# GoogleTest tests declare in separate library

Tags: testing, compilation, googletest

I have a lot of auto-generated tests using the GoogleTest framework.
Currently each test is in a .cpp file which is included in a larger "Tests.cpp" file, which is then included in the main file.
When trying to compile all of them my computer freezes.
I've assumed it is because it is trying to compile them in a single output file.
Is there a way to write each test fixture in a "normal" way, having an output file for each test fixture/case and then linking them?

Thanks

Comment: "Is there a way to write each test fixture in a "normal" way, having an output file for each test fixture/case and then linking them?" Certainly, it is just the *normal* way. You have not made it all all clear what is stopping you.

Comment: Consider adding the code samples and details regarding your build environment... Most of us have not yet mastered the ability to read random stranger's minds via the internet in order to help them :/

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" way to use GoogleTest is to put the tests in a separate project from the project you wish to test, i.e. if you wish to test your project **Foo** you should place you tests in (e.g.) the **FooTest** project.

In the **FooTest** project you main should look something like this:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And individual test should look like this:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "IntComparer.h"

namespace
{
class IntComparerTest : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:
    IntComparerTest () { ... };
    virtual ~IntComparerTest () { ... };
};

TEST_F(IntComparerTest, biggerThanZero)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(IntComparer::inputBiggerThanZero(1));
}

TEST_F(IntComparerTest, biggerThanZero_false)
{
    EXPECT_FALSE(IntComparer::inputBiggerThanZero(-1));
}
}
```

Note that the inclusion of `gtest.h` and the `TEST_F` macro cause the test cases to be **automatically** (if `IntComparer.cpp` is compiled and linked in the test project) registered by test framework (and thus found/run when the test executable is run) - there is **NO** need to include the `IntComparer.cpp` **anywhere**.

That said, you have not specified your build environment, nor provided any sample code on where you are stuck, so I cannot give you any advice beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what you are doing. Normally in C++ you should  not include cpp file. We need the output you get from the compiler.

One usual way is to have one unit of compilation (one cpp and one header file) for one test fixture and associated test cases.

GoogleTest is nothing more than a C++ library with heavy and complex macros. Usual rules of C++ programming applies.

Comment: What i meant was that if i don't have the part where i declare each test case in the main file included somewhere, it doesn't appear in the list of tests. If the .cpp file where all test cases are declared is not included in the main file, and just added to the main library, then the tests don't appear. It wasn't actually a hpp/cpp question, it's more how to make sure each test case is actually added to the list if compiling them in separate object files.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear. You must show the structure of your project if you want help.
Google test framework provides 3 majors macros, TEST, TEST_F and TEST_P.  When using  TEST or TEST_F, you should not have anything to do in the main except invoking 
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
 int r =  RUN_ALL_TESTS();
This should be enough to have every tests  executed.
If you use parameterized test, than you also have to register them via the INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P macro.

Comment: OK, so i have main.cpp where i call InitGoogleTest and RUN_ALL_TEST().

Comment: Sorry, continuing from the previous:In another file, lets say for the sake of it .hpp where i have the TestFixture definition and .cpp where i have the implementation and each test case using TEST_F. If i only include in the library (i am using jamfile build system) the .cpp file in the same library as the main.cpp, when i run --gtest_list_tests i can't find it. If i were to include the cpp then it appears. Maybe it's because of the build system.